# Insert in yii2 from different controller

Tags: sql, yii2, query-builder

I am tring to insert data in a table.

trying like this but it`s not working.

```
$sql = $queryBuilder->insert(' HRMS_candidateEducation', [
                 'HRMS_candidateEducationCandidateID' => $candidateID,
                 'HRMS_candidateEducationDegree' => $data['Degree'.$i],
                 'HRMS_candidateEducationUniversity' => $data['University'.$i],
                 'HRMS_candidateEducationCollege' => $data['College'.$i],
                 'HRMS_candidateEducationYear' => $data['Specilization'.$i], 
                 'HRMS_candidateEducationSpecilization' => $data['Specilization'.$i],
                ], $params);
```

What is incorrect?

using

```
use yii\db\QueryBuilder;
use app\models\CandidateEducation;
```

Comment: what errors you got?

Comment: Why you do not use save method of CandidateEducation's AR class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function seem only create the SQL statement [see doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#insert%28%29-detail)

> insert()  Creates an INSERT command

for executing the command i think you shoul try this way

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->
 insert(' HRMS_candidateEducation', [
             'HRMS_candidateEducationCandidateID' => $candidateID,
             'HRMS_candidateEducationDegree' => $data['Degree'.$i],
             'HRMS_candidateEducationUniversity' => $data['University'.$i],
             'HRMS_candidateEducationCollege' => $data['College'.$i],
             'HRMS_candidateEducationYear' => $data['Specilization'.$i], 
             'HRMS_candidateEducationSpecilization' => $data['Specilization'.$i],
            ], $params)->
 execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution to my question.

This is what i did. by following this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models).

```
public function actionCreate()
{
  $a=new A;
  $b=new B;
 if(isset($_POST['A'], $_POST['B']))
{
    // populate input data to $a and $b
    $a->attributes=$_POST['A'];
    $b->attributes=$_POST['B'];

    // validate BOTH $a and $b
    $valid=$a->validate();
    $valid=$b->validate() && $valid;

    if($valid)
    {
        // use false parameter to disable validation
        $a->save(false);
        $b->save(false);
        // ...redirect to another page
    }
}

$this->render('create', array(
    'a'=>$a,
    'b'=>$b,
));
```

}